# For unbatched 2-D input, hx should also be 2-D but got 3-D tensor

Tags: pytorch

the below is my seq model:
import torch.nn as nn

class Encoder(nn.Module):
def **init**(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, dropout_p):
super(Encoder, self).**init**()
self.input_size = input_size
self.hidden_size = hidden_size
self.num_layers = num_layers
self.dropout_p = dropout_p

```
    # Use a GRU layer instead of an LSTM layer
    self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, dropout=dropout_p, batch_first=True)

def forward(self, x):
    # x = [batch size, sequence length, input size] for GRU
    # Forward propagate GRU
    h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
    out, hn = self.gru(x, h0)
    return out, hn
```

class Decoder(nn.Module):
def **init**(self, input_size, output_size, hidden_size, num_layers, dropout_p):
super(Decoder, self).**init**()
self.input_size = input_size
self.output_size = output_size
self.hidden_size = hidden_size
self.num_layers = num_layers
self.dropout = dropout_p

```
    # Use a GRU layer instead of an LSTM layer
    self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, dropout=dropout_p, batch_first=True)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    # Set decoder weights to be fixed unconditional
    for param in self.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False

def forward(self, x, h):
    # Ensure that the input x has the correct shape (batch size, sequence length, input size)

    output, h = self.gru(x, h)
    prediction = self.fc(output.squeeze(1))  # Squeeze to remove the sequence length dimension

    return prediction, h
```

class Seq2Seq(nn.Module):
def **init**(self, encoder, decoder, device):
super(Seq2Seq, self).**init**()
self.encoder = encoder
self.decoder = decoder
self.device = device

```
def forward(self, x, target, teacher_forcing_ratio=0.5):
    batch_size, target_length, output_size = target.shape
    output = torch.zeros(batch_size, target_length, output_size).to(self.device)

    # Encode the input sequence
    encoder_output, encoder_hidden = self.encoder(x)

    # Initialize the first input to the decoder
    input = target

    for t in range(1, target_length):
        # Pass the input and previous hidden state to the decoder
        decoder_output, decoder_hidden = self.decoder(input, encoder_hidden)
        output = decoder_output  # Store the decoder output

        # Decide whether to use teacher forcing or not
        use_teacher_forcing = random.random() < teacher_forcing_ratio

        # Update the input for the next time step
        if use_teacher_forcing:
            input = target  # Use the ground truth as input
        else:
            input = decoder_output.argmax(1)  # Use the predicted output as input

    return output
```

I try to build the sequence-to-sequence model. but I got the error For unbatched 2-D input, hx should also be 2-D but got 3-D tensor